# Changing html button style without changing functionality

Tags: html, css, django, button

I'm new to HTML and CSS. I have a default button working well in HTML, but I would like to change its appearance without changing its functionality at all.

This is my code in HTML:

```
<a><input type="submit" class="save btn boton-no" value= "HECHO"><a/>
```

And this one is the style I would like the button to have, is my CSS file:

```
#boton-no{
    color: #AF1C24;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 30pt;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 35%;
}
```

How can I apply this style to my button? I've tried several things like changing the "id", the "style", ... but the button doesn't change its appearance or it changes both its style and functionality...

Could you help me, please?? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Use `.boton-no` instead of `#boton-no`. Also, you have an error: you have `</input>` at the end where you should only have `>`. And you can't have an <input> in an <a> element (although that shouldn't influence the styling). Oh, and `</a>` is misspelled too.

Comment: Ok, thanks @MrLister, but I have no idea with HTML & CSS. and I'm a bit confused.. So, how could I write it correctly?

Comment: symlink's answer below is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with simplified CSS. Also the hashtag symbol targets ids, not classes.

```css
#boton-no{
    color: #AF1C24;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 40pt;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="save btn" id="boton-no" value= "HECHO" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector `#boton-no` applies to an element with `id=boton-no`. You should be using class sector, which look like this: `.boton-no`. The style is applied to all elements which have the `button-no` class. So your CSS should be looking like this:

```
.boton-no {
    color: #AF1C24;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 30pt;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 35%;
}
```

You can read more about CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).